# Color decorator doesn't work in files with lots of lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a 10,000+ line css file, and color decorators only work for about the top 50% of the file. I've been looking everywhere for a setting to change the number of lines the built in VS Code color decorator feature will work on, but can't seem to find it, anyone know how to make it work or is there an extension that won't give up after any number of lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [v1.75 Release Notes: Color Decorators Limit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#color-decorators-limit):

> The number of color decorators that are shown in the editor is limited
> to 500. This is to prevent performance issues when a file contains a
> large number of colors. It now can be configured via the new
> `editor.colorDecoratorsLimit` setting.

Answer (score 0):

`File->Preferences->Settings->search for "Color Decorators Limit"->change the values(default as 500)`
I usually change it to 1000